# Android Pager Adapter, onClick

Tags: java, android

I've been coding an Android app and faced a little problem. I've tried to implement a tutorial using a Pager Adapter extended Class ( see below code ) and making some background wallpapers that show how the app works. Right now you can go from page to page swiping your finger through the screen. I would like to change the screen by touching it. Is that possible? if so, how can it be done? i supose it might be by using an onClick method.

Thanks on advance and sorry for my English.

tutorial.java

```
    public class tutorial extends Activity {

    int currentPage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

       //set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
        this.setContentView(R.layout.tutorial_pannels_pager);

        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();

        final ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tutorial_pannel);

        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);









    }


}
```

MyPagerAdapter.java

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


    // set number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 7;
    }


    // Set each screen's content
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final View container, final int position) {
        Context context = container.getContext();
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        // Add elements
        TextView textItem = new TextView(context);



        switch (position) {
        case 0:
           layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tut_0);

           break;
        case 1:
           layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tut_1);

           break;
        case 2:
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tut_2);

            break;

        case 3:
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tut_3);

            break;
        case 4:
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tut_4);

            break;
        case 5:
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tut_5);

            break;
        case 6:
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tut_6);
            break;
    }
    layout.addView(textItem);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(layout, 0); // This is the line I added
    return layout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
            ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }

}
```

tutorial_pannels_pager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tutorial_pannel"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to pass a interface to the adapter. This example should enlighten you:

```
  public interface OnItemClick{
    void onClick(int position);
  }
```

Next you should implement this interface and add the code to manually change the view. Next pass an instance of this interface to the adapter. Like this:

```
   MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(new OnItemClick(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(int position)
        {
            myPager.setCurrentItem(position+1); //example.. change it to your needs
        }
    });
```

Next on your adapter you need save an instance to this interface that was passed in the constructor and then call it when you click on the layout, for example.

```
   layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            interface.onClick(position);
        }
    });
```

This is just the basics as you need to work on it by yourself. However it's more than necessary to reach the final solution.

Good work.